# Add these symbols in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have an `UILabel` for which text is assigned by parsing .The text that in `UILabel` will be in `1234567890` format but i want this as `(123) 456-7890`  .

How can i do this .Is there any way

Please help me

Comment: You always want the first three in the brackets and an - after next three.. Always you need the same format??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSString *s = @"1234567890";
    NSMutableString *mu = [NSMutableString stringWithString:s];
    [mu insertString:@"(" atIndex:0];
    [mu insertString:@")" atIndex:4];
    [mu insertString:@" " atIndex:5];
    [mu insertString:@"-" atIndex:9];
     NSLog(@" s == %@ ", mu);
yourlable.text = mu;
```